# Add buttons to a dialog box in header or below header

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on a project where I have to popup a dialog box after page load. I completed the task what ever it was but after spending two days on it now my client says that I need buttons at the top like jQuery UI tabs. So I have to put buttons. I can also do it with help of tabs but it will destroy my two days effort and thats why I want to have three anchor tag at the header of dialog box or below the header in the body of dialog box. but I don't know is it possible as I get dialog box html on fly so any suggestion for it guys.

I don't want you guys do it for me but need some assistance for how to do it and referral link any online documentation for it I will study it myself and will do it.

thanks in advance

Comment: Need example code to help you

Comment: infact i cannot post code here as i am going to edit jquery-ui file and as on fly it add close button i also want to edit it so that it could add some links on fly beside the close button this is what i want hope you get my point